# check whether a table exists in ms access through jdbc

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

can somebody tell me how can I check whether a table exists in microsoft access by using java database connectivity. After searching I go something like 
    If Not IsNull(DlookUp("Name","MSysObjects","Name='TableName'")) Then
    'Table Exists
I tried to implement the same thing in jdbc program

```
import java.sql.*;
class CheckTable{
public static void main(String [] rak){
 boolean flag;
 try{
 flag=false;
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
 String dataSourceName="test"; 
 String dbURL="jdbc:odbc:"+dataSourceName;
 Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,"","");
 Statement s=con.createStatement(); 
//s.execute("create table xyz (name text, hiredate date)");
//s.execute("insert into xyz values('xz1','22-dec-2005')");
// s.execute("insert into xyz values('pr','2-21-2009')");
 s.execute(" If Not IsNull(DlookUp('Name','MSysObjects',"Name='xyz'")) Then "+ flag=true + ");

 /* 
      ResultSet rs=s.getResultSet();
  if (rs!=null){
       while(rs.next()){
       System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+rs.getString(2));
      }}
  */      
 }
 catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(" table exists :"+flag);
   }
  }
```

I am getting error at s.execute() statement please help me with the syntax.
the errors I am getting are:
')' expected
illegal start of expression
unclosed character literal
not a statement
; excepted 
all the errors are on line  s.execute(" If Not IsNull(DlookUp('Name','MSysObjects',"Name='xyz'")) Then "+ flag=true + ");

Comment: You might like to look for  `getMetaData` and `getTables`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `select 1 from TABLE_NAME`. This will throw an `SQLException` if the table doesn't exist. Examine the `SQLState` and `errorCode` - there will be a specific value for this case.

Unfortunately, the codes are different for every database, so you will have to print them once on the console and then copy the correct values in your exception handler.

Comment: Correct. There are other ways (like getting the metadata and looking through the table names) but that isn't simple to get right, either. My approach always works. Usually, I collect these codes in a helper class so that I can say `AccessHelper.isTableNotFound( e )`